# $sce.trustAsHtml return Error : TypeError: html.indexOf is not a function

Tags: angularjs

Code example :

```
<p ng-bind-html="htmlcode | unsafe"></p> 

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ["ngSanitize"]);

myApp.controller('helloController',  ["$scope", "$sce", function ($scope, $sce) {

    $scope.htmlcode="text <b>ng-bind-html</b>";

}
}])
 .filter('unsafe', function($sce) { return $sce.trustAsHtml; });
```

> TypeError: html.indexOf is not a function

I include "santize.js".

Comment: You have another problem that code works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/yupds5ky/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bracket typo.

```
myApp.controller('helloController',  ["$scope", "$sce", function ($scope, $sce) {

    $scope.htmlcode="text <b>ng-bind-html</b>";

}])
.filter('unsafe', function($sce) { return $sce.trustAsHtml; });
```

Remove the extra bracket and should work.

Answer (score 1):

You don't include the part with `indexOf` NOR your var `html`. But anyway it's a common problem. TrustAsHtml return an Object not a string. So you can't use `indexOf` on it. You have to use a second function to get the string.

```
 var htmlText = "<b>Hello</b>";
 var value =  $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlText);
 var yourString = $sce.getTrustedHtml(value);
 var index = yourString.indexOf("e");
```